# How can I add update and delete button on Autocomplete menu using Material-ui with React.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build autocomplete component that I can add, update and delete option in select menu while it is open.

Thanks to material-ui Autocomplete [Creatable component](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete), I can easily do add action However there is no reference about rest of action.(update & delete)

[image]

Here is the image of example I want to creat. Name and buttons would be options of select menu.

How can I create option like this above? Should I manupulate dom of each options as well?

Comment: You can use `Multiple values` in `material-ui Autocomplete` it will give you the option for remove add and update, `example` : https://codesandbox.io/s/xqex8

Answer (score -1):

```
const TodoApp = () => {
const [inputArray, setInputArray] = useState([])
  return (
 <div>
  {
    inputArray.map(item => (
    <input id={item.id} value={item.value)/>
)
)
  }
<button onClick={() => setinputArray(s => [...s, {id: 1231231313}])}>
</div>  
)
}
```